# Spotify remove a track from a playlist not owned by the user

Tags: node.js, service, spotify

As you might know, the permission system from Spotify isn't the best. You can just mark a playlist collaborative, and every single spotify user can edit the Playlist without my approval. Therefore, I am writing an application (using Spotify Web Api, node and mysql) that gives the user more control over the collaborative playlists. It should support sub-playlists, votes and a small permission system, which allows just some users to modify the playlist.

In order for that to work, I need a service running all the time in the background. This service should sync my version of the playlist with spotify. Because the user, who owns the playlist, will most likely not be logged in, i have created a special Spotify User for my service. Now, i have to edit the collaborative Playlist using this spotify user.

When i try to delete some Tracks from such a playlist, i get the following answer:

```
{
    "error" : 
    {
        "status" : 403,
        "message" : "You cannot remove tracks from a playlist you don't own."
    }
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to delete a Track from a playlist i don't own? And if not, Do you have any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: You could always programmatically hack into the account that owns the playlist ;) That would work.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know if there is a way to delete a Track from a playlist i don't own?

This isn't possible, even if the playlist is collaborative.

> And if not, Do you have any idea how to get around this problem?

One way is to create a playlist owned and edited by a user that you control. Server-side you'd keep an access token for that user, and simply refresh it when necessary. Since the refresh token lasts forever, you'd never have to require a user to go through any form of authentication flow.

Hope this helped!